# Why is high energy required if we want to send a message in a short amount of time?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, black-holes, quantum-information, string-theory, hawking-radiation

I am somewhat puzzled by the following statement

"If Alice, after crossing the horizon, has less than a Planck time to communicate with Bob about
the status of her qubits, then she is required to send her message to Bob using super-Planckian
frequencies."

which is made in ref. https://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.4025.pdf. I do understand the typical argument that we need high frequencies if we want to resolve a short distance in spacetime. It would seem to me that this is kind of the argument that is being made here, but we are not talking about resolving any small distance in spacetime - we are simply talking about sending a message, possibly a photon and I don't see how the two connect. The only reasonable thing I see is the uncertainty relation time-energy but that just tells us something about the uncertainty in the energy. I don't understand why we cannot still send a photon with lower energy even if its uncertainty is big - I guess one could argue it is still a problem that the uncertainty is big, but that is different from saying that the energy must necessarily be big.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually much simpler than that. If you have a time < T to send a message, you would need to use a frequency > 1/T to send a single period of your signal. So given < Planck time, you need a frequency > Planck frequency, a super-Planckian frequency.

Even if all Alice does is turn on a signal from 0 to 1 within time T, the Fourier transform of such a signal would show that it contains super-Planckian frequencies.